# Derivative of equalities [solved]

Tags: calculus

In a equality where $f(x)=g(x)$, if I take the derivative of both sides, does the equality still persists?

(I'm solving a series of equations like "$e^x=\ln{x}$" and I thought that taking the derivative of both sides would help a lot,  I searched on the internet and I didn't find anything, so I decided to ask here)

Comment: How are the functions $e^x$ and $\ln{x}$ equal?

Comment: Im sorry, I didnt explain very well, what I am trying to Discover is the intersection of the functions, in other words, the solution of this equation

Comment: It is not true that if $f(x)=g(x)$ at some point $x=x_0$ then $f'(x_0)$ must equal $g'(x_0)$.  Consider $f(x)=0$, $g(x)=x$ and $x_0=0$.

Comment: So I cant take the derivative of both sides to solve the equality?

Answer (score 2):

If the equation (identity) holds for all values of $x$ , such as $$\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x) = 1,$$
then you can derivatives on both sides of the equation. But, if you are solving an equation, such as $$x^3=1,$$
then solving for $x$ using the derivatives as $$\frac{d}{dx}(x^3) = 3x^2 = 0 \implies x = 0$$ is not necessarily correct.

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x)=g(x)$ for *all* $x$ in an open interval, then also $f'(x)=g'(x)$ for all $x$ in that interval (provided both derivatives exist - or at least one exists, and the existence of the other follows from here).

If $f(x)=g(x)$ holds only at isolated points, then nothing can be said about the derivatives. We have only an equation between numbers, not functions. Hence only applying the same "number-input" operations to both sides produces a new valid equality (e.g., $27f(x)^2=27g(x)^2$ holds for all $x$ where $f(x)=g(x)$ - and perhaps for a few additional values of $x$). A "function-input" operation such as taking the derivative may fail in that case.

---

Simple counter exmaple: In order to solve $3x=9$, it is a bad idea to take derivatives of both sides as that would yield $3=0$.

Answer (score 0):

If you are given that 
$$
f(x)=g(x) \quad\text{ for all } x\in \mathbb R,
$$
then it follows that
$$
f'(x)=g'(x)\quad \text{ for all } x\in \mathbb R.
$$
However, if you are only given that
$$
f(x_0) = g(x_0) \quad\text{ for a particular value of }x_0,
$$
then it does **not** follow that
$$
f'(x_0) = g'(x_0) \quad\text{ for that particular value of }x_0.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Just because $f(x) = g(x)$, $f'(x)$ does not have to equal $g'(x)$. For example, if $f(x) = x^2$ and $g(x) = x$, they intersect at $(1,1)$. But $f'(1) = 2$ and $g'(1) = 1$, which are not equal.

Answer (score 0):

Ah so this is actually a very interesting question,

There is a massive difference between:

$$ f(x) = g(x) $$

and $$f = g$$

The former states there is a point $x$ where $f=g$ whereas the latter is a statement about two functions independent of their domain.

In the case of $f=g$ it then must be true that $f' = g'$ since you can "differentiate" both functions.

In the original expression $f(x)$ really is a number, its some number that you find using $f$ about an unknown but SOLVABLE quantity called $x$. So if 
$$ f(x) = g(x) $$

Then differentiating both sides yields

$$ 0 = 0 $$

which gives no information. Another way to look at this that $f(x)=g(x)$ states that there is an $x$ such that $f = g$ and from here it's again easy to say why that doesn't gaurantee that $f' = g'$ on this $x$. Consider say $f = \sin(x)$ and $g = 0$ and let $x = 0$

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, it is not always the case that a solution of $f(x) = g(x) $ is also a solution of $f'(x) = g'(x)$, where $f'(x)$ and $g'(x)$ is the derivative of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ respectively.

A clear counterexample, when $f(x) = x^2$ and $g(x) = x$:

$f(x) = g(x) \iff x^2 = x$ has two solutions: $x=0$ and $x=1$.
However,

$f'(x) = g'(x) \iff 2x = 1$ has one solution: $x=\frac{1}{2}$.

The relation in question, $f(x) = g(x) \to f'(x) = g'(x)$, is only true for the values of $x$ where the functions are tangential to each other.